# Why does StageVideo not work locally in IE?

Tags: windows, flash, apache-flex, internet-explorer-9, netstream

I'm having troubles testing a StageVideo file locally. The HTML file that contains the swf loads perfectly in Chrome & FireFox, but when I go to open it in Internet Explorer 9 nothing happens (it just shows a white screen).

I've added the permissions for the location to the 'Global Security Settings' tab of the Flash settings manager (on the Macromedia website). I've also checked in the IE9 settings to make sure that it allows GPU rendering.

Has anyone encountered anything similar or have any suggestions as to why it might be blocked in IE9?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My gut feeling is that you don't have the latest Flash Player for IE, but do have it for Chrome/FF since they're 2 different versions.  The swf probably doesn't even load up because of the Flash Player requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have FP11 Beta installed, but a similar thing happens in 10.3.